# Change background color of a div with a specific class- js

Tags: javascript, css

I have an array comprising of `div` elements:
js:

```
 //where arr : [<div class="tag tag-selected tag-over" style="background-color:#C8C8C8;"><div class="inner">Test</div></div>, 
<div class="tag tag-selected" style="background-color:#C8C8C8;"><div class="inner">Test2</div></div>,
<div class="tag tag-selected" style="background-color:#C8C8C8;"><div class="inner">Test3</div></div>]
    Ext.iterate(arr, function(key) {
       console.log(key);//results in <div class="tag tag-selected" style="background-color:#C8C8C8;"><div class="inner">Test</div></div>
    });
```

In the iteration i'm looking for a `class="tag-over"`,as I'm trying to change the background color of the `div` who does not have `class="tag-over"`, is there a simple precise way to do this?

Thanks~

Comment: is `style="background-color:#c8c8c8;"` a requirement, or can you move to a stylesheet? If your purpose is only changing background based on the presence or absence of a class, there's a css only solution.

Comment: JS will work as well!

Comment: the div element comes from a json store, so no i may not be able to move it to css stylesheet

Comment: If you are appending those elements from json then I recommend you target the element you are using to append them to > `document.getElelmentById().getElementsByTagName('div')` and loop through those. A simple `if` condition in your loop to check for `tag-over`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`div` who does not have `class="tag-over"`

```
div:not(.tag-over) {
  /* Specify color you want */
  background-color: purple;
}
```

Comment: this is in css, I was looking to do in extjs so that im able to do more than just styling